# Density of a set in [-1,1]

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

It is well known that the set $\{\sin m\}_{m=0}^\infty$ is dense in  $[-1,1]$.

How to prove that $\{a \sin m+b\sin(m+1)\}_{m=0}^\infty$ is dense also in a set Q contains $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $1$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$, the set $S=\{(\cos m,\sin m):m\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in the unit circle $C$.  Elementary trigonometry tell us that  $a\sin(m)+b\sin(m+1)=A\cos m + B\sin m$, where $A=b\sin1$ and $B=a+b\cos1$.  So your set is dense in the image of $C$ under the map $(x,y)\mapsto Ax+By$. Unless $A=B=0$, this image will be an interval of positive length.  Namely, dense in the interval $(-L,L)$, where $L=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kimchilover

Comment: Please Prof. @Kimchilover, would you please investigate how you get the value of $L=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$? (Sorry for delay in response, as there was a problem in my Computer), Raafat

Comment: What is the maximum of $Ax+By$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$?  Answer (by Lagrange multipliers, if you like):  when $(x,y)$ is a scalar multiple of $(A,B)$.  And the minimum when $(x,y)$ is diametrically opposite: the same scalar multiple of $-(x,y)$.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes it has helped me! Thank you very much @kimchilover !